# xrdp to Ubuntu machine not working from external network

Tags: networking, server, remote-desktop, firewall

I have a Ubuntu machine that I would like external users to connect to using RDP. Connecting from an internal network works perfectly fine.

But users outside of my network,who use the public IP, can not connect using RDP. Although they can SSH. What could be the reason?

Note that I have checked the following already:

**Port 3389 is listening to incoming connections**

```
sudo netstat -an | grep "LISTEN" | grep ":3389"

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3389            0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN
```

---

**If it is a Firewall relevant issue I have issued the following command**

```
sudo ufw disable

Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
```

- I have installed Ubuntu mate, and it works fine when connecting from a computer internal to the network
- I have issued the command `/etc/init.d/xrdp start`
- I tried the above based on what was discussed in

[Unable to do remote desktop using xrdp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234856/unable-to-do-remote-desktop-using-xrdp][1])

What else can I try to enable access using RDP from the outside world?

Thank you!